# Created kestrel service on Ubuntu stopped with error (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, kestrel

I create a service in /etc/systemd/system as follow :

```
$ cd /etc/systemd/system
$ sudo nano test.service
```

Add the following content

```
[Unit]
Description=test app

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/test-app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/test-app/Test.App.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=test
User=ubuntu
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after save the service
run following commands

```
$ sudo systemctl enable test.service
$ sudo systemctl start test.service
$ sudo systemctl status test.service
```

but display this error

```
test.service - test app
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-02-15 10:41:19 UTC; 8s ago
  Process: 24631 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/test-app/Test.App.dll (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 24631 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
```

The user (ubuntu) is exist and have proper ownership of the app's files

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact issue. I tried permissions, path length, using different directories. But the issue was a small mistake in the Working Directory path. Fixed, and all worked well.

Comment: What was the mistake in the Working Directory path?

Comment: Misspelled name of one of the directories of the path, i.e. the provided path to the .NET app was not correct. I don't know why my answer was downvoted. When I had this issue I spent time investigating it while I'm sure my configs are OK, but found this small mistake to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrong directory path or don't permission to the directory.
I have tested with root user on centos for Kestrel riht now.